# window phone 8.1 build app for different screen size

Tags: c#, xaml

I'm newer in window phone.
So, i use visual studio 2013 to build first app for window phone 8.1.
I test on emulator WVGA 4 inch, everything is ok.
this is my simple xaml:

```
<Grid>
<ScrollViewer>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock x:Name="tbCheck" Margin="10,0,0,0" FontSize="20" Text="check"/>
        <ListView x:Name="lvInfo" SelectionChanged="lvInfo_SelectionChanged">
            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapGrid MaximumRowsOrColumns="5" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border BorderThickness="3" CornerRadius="3" Margin="10,0,10,10" BorderBrush="#ffffff">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                            <Image Margin="5,5,5,5" Width="100" Height="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Source="{Binding ImgInfo}"/>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock FontSize="28" Text="{Binding NameInfo}"/>
                                <TextBlock Margin="0,5,0,5" FontSize="18" Text="{Binding AgeInfo}"/>
                                <TextBlock FontSize="18" Text="{Binding GenderInfo}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

i know i need to fix for different screen size to make everything like on WVGA 4 inch, but i don't know how to do that.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Few things to point out.**

**1)** Windows Phone OS Automatically sets the FontSize of Items based on the Font Size of OS. You do not need to explicitly Set the FontSize of TextBoxes. However if you want to make FontSize of your items explicitly larger or smaller than others, use [Theme Resources](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff769552(v=vs.105).aspx)

See Table Below:

[image]

**2)** Your first `StackPanel` Inside DataTemplate `HorizontalAlignment` is set to `Left`. Unless it is required by Design, Do not use it. Instead use a `Grid`

Replace your `StackPanel` with `Grid` as below.

```
<Border BorderThickness="3" CornerRadius="3" Margin="10,0,10,10" BorderBrush="#ffffff">
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Image Margin="5" Width="100" Height="100"  Source="{Binding ImgInfo}"/>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
            <TextBlock FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeLarge}" Text="{Binding NameInfo}"/>
            <TextBlock Margin="0,5" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeSmall}" Text="{Binding AgeInfo}"/>
            <TextBlock FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeSmall}" Text="{Binding GenderInfo}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

Now your `ListViewItem` will consume full space on device irrespective of ScreenSize and looks same on all resolutions.

Comment: that mean when display on 4 inch screen or 6 inch screen or 8 inch screen, it look same with other? and about width and height of image, how to make it looks same on all resolutions?

Comment: @1234abcd try it out yourself.